# How to call javascript Function in Oracle APEX on button click in dynamic action?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oracle-apex, stopwatch

I have javascript of stopwatch i want to start stop with oracle apex button. i create button and create dynamic action with Execute Javascript expression and paste javasctipt but it doesn't run.

```
var x;
var startstop = 0;

function startStop() { /* Toggle StartStop */

  startstop = startstop + 1;

  if (startstop === 1) {
    start();
    document.getElementById("start").innerHTML = "Stop";
  } else if (startstop === 2) {
    document.getElementById("start").innerHTML = "Start";
    startstop = 0;
    stop();
  }

}


function start() {
  x = setInterval(timer, 10);
} /* Start */

function stop() {
  clearInterval(x);
} /* Stop */

var milisec = 0;
var sec = 0; /* holds incrementing value */
var min = 0;
var hour = 0;

/* Contains and outputs returned value of  function checkTime */

var miliSecOut = 0;
var secOut = 0;
var minOut = 0;
var hourOut = 0;

/* Output variable End */


function timer() {
  /* Main Timer */


  miliSecOut = checkTime(milisec);
  secOut = checkTime(sec);
  minOut = checkTime(min);
  hourOut = checkTime(hour);

  milisec = ++milisec;

  if (milisec === 100) {
    milisec = 0;
    sec = ++sec;
  }

  if (sec == 60) {
    min = ++min;
    sec = 0;
  }

  if (min == 60) {
    min = 0;
    hour = ++hour;

  }


  document.getElementById("milisec").innerHTML = miliSecOut;
  document.getElementById("sec").innerHTML = secOut;
  document.getElementById("min").innerHTML = minOut;
  document.getElementById("hour").innerHTML = hourOut;

}


/* Adds 0 when value is <10 */


function checkTime(i) {
  if (i < 10) {
    i = "0" + i;
  }
  return i;
}

function reset() {


  /*Reset*/

  milisec = 0;
  sec = 0;
  min = 0
  hour = 0;

  document.getElementById("milisec").innerHTML = "00";
  document.getElementById("sec").innerHTML = "00";
  document.getElementById("min").innerHTML = "00";
  document.getElementById("hour").innerHTML = "00";

}
```

this is html code. this heading i added into static content. I think this fucntion need to call in button of oracle apex onclick="startStop()"

```
<h1>
  <span id="hour">00</span> :
  <span id="min">00</span> :
  <span id="sec">00</span> :
  <span id="milisec">00</span>
</h1>

<button onclick="startStop()" id="start">Start</button>
<button onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not completely sure, because your problem description isn't 100% clear, but how is the dynamic action connected to your button?

You create the button with your HTML code, but that means the button does not exist before runtime and you can't assign the dynamic action to it in the page designer?

When is your javascript code triggered? Because I think that is the issue why your code is not beeing executed.

**Answer:**

If you want to generate the buttons like this, you need to initialize your functions for the whole page.

In the page designer click on your page on the left and then go to: `"JavaScript" > "Function and Global Variable Declaration"` on the right and there you have to declare your functions.

Now the button you create in your header, can use the `startStop()` function and will execute your code.

I haven't checked your code so I don't know if it will work as intended, but this way you can at least execute it.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example that makes use of Dynamic Actions, though most of the logic will be in a JavaScript module loaded via the page attributes.

Given this HTML (note there are no buttons):

```
<div style="line-height: 1.5; font-size: 3.2rem; font-weight: 500">
  <span id="hour">00</span> :
  <span id="min">00</span> :
  <span id="sec">00</span> :
  <span id="milisec">00</span>
</div>
```

Add the following to the **Execute when Page Loads** attribute of the page. This will create a JavaScript module (revealing module pattern) that only exposes two functions which are later added as global methods on the window object:

```
var timerModule = (function() {
  var startElmtId = 'START';
  var miliSecElmtId = 'milisec';
  var secElmtId = 'sec';
  var minElmtId = 'min';
  var hourElmtId = 'hour';

  var $startBtn = $('#' + startElmtId);
  var timerRef;

  var milisec = 0;
  var sec = 0;
  var min = 0;
  var hour = 0;

  var miliSecOut = 0;
  var miliSecElmt = document.getElementById(miliSecElmtId);
  var secOut = 0;
  var secElmt = document.getElementById(secElmtId);
  var minOut = 0;
  var minElmt = document.getElementById(minElmtId);
  var hourOut = 0;
  var hourElmt = document.getElementById(hourElmtId);

  function startStop() {
    if (timerRef === undefined) {
      $startBtn.children('span').text("Stop");
      start();
    } else {
      $startBtn.children('span').text("Start");
      stop();
    }
  }

  function start() {
    timerRef = setInterval(timer, 10);
  }

  function stop() {
    clearInterval(timerRef);
    timerRef = undefined;
  }

  function timer() {
    miliSecOut = checkTime(milisec);
    secOut = checkTime(sec);
    minOut = checkTime(min);
    hourOut = checkTime(hour);

    milisec = ++milisec;

    if (milisec === 100) {
      milisec = 0;
      sec = ++sec;
    }

    if (sec == 60) {
      min = ++min;
      sec = 0;
    }

    if (min == 60) {
      min = 0;
      hour = ++hour;
    }

    miliSecElmt.innerHTML = miliSecOut;
    secElmt.innerHTML = secOut;
    minElmt.innerHTML = minOut;
    hourElmt.innerHTML = hourOut;
  }

  /* Adds 0 when value is <10 */
  function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {
      i = "0" + i;
    }
    return i;
  }

  function reset() {
    milisec = 0;
    sec = 0;
    min = 0
    hour = 0;

    miliSecElmt.innerHTML = "00";
    secElmt.innerHTML = "00";
    minElmt.innerHTML = "00";
    hourElmt.innerHTML = "00";
  }

  return {
    startStop: startStop,
    reset: reset
  };
})();

window.startStop = timerModule.startStop;
window.reset = timerModule.reset;
```

Next, create two buttons, one named START and another named RESET. For the start button, be sure to set the static ID to START.

Then create a Dynamic Action for the click event START button. Set the action to Execute JavaScript Code and set the code to `startStop();`

Finally, add a Dynamic Action for the click event RESET button. Set the action to Execute JavaScript Code to `reset();`

Just a few notes:

1. The HTML no longer has the buttons, the example uses regular APEX buttons. The code that updates
2. I cached the HTML elements since they were being referred to so frequently.
3. Because the code uses the revealing module pattern, only two functions needed to be exposed globally.

Comment: your suggestion is right, but what if i apply this code and i need some dynamic action on same button then no way to add dynamic action to execute pl/sql code or any other?

Comment: This is a fair point, but you provided code with custom HTML that that didn't use Dynamic Actions (it used inline event handlers), so I provided a more custom solution. Before I update this to use Dynamic Actions, please tell me. Do you plan to use these custom buttons or regular APEX region/item buttons?

Comment: i have to use both.. because some of my pl/sql code are running already i just want to add a counter on Button  Click.

Comment: You have to use both what? Both types of buttons? Why? You can have more than one action with a Dynamic Action. For example, on click of "normal" button, action 1) start timer via Execute JavaScript and action 2) execute PL/SQL. Would that work?

Comment: I've updated the answer to use Dynamic Actions. Please have a look.